# error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am learning React and I faced this error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I've checked all the previous questions related to similar errors but can't find out what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



 class   MyForm extends React.Component {


 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     drug: '',
     disease:'',
     type:''
   };
 }
  render() {
  const { drug , disease , type } = this.state
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }
    return (
      <form>


        <p>Drug</p>
        <input
          type="text" name="drug" value={drug}
          />


     <p>disease</p>
        <input
          type="text" name="disease" value={disease}
          />



        <p>type</p>
        <input
          type="number" name="type" value={type}
          />



      </form>
    );
  }
}



export default MyForm
```

Comment: Hi Dyab, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Always remember the thumb rule.

**You should never write `setState` in `render` function.**

You need to take `myChangeHandler` out of the `render` function and provide the same to your input's.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          drug: '',
          disease: '',
          type: ''
      };
  }

  //Always keep setState out of the render function
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { drug, disease, type } = this.state
    return (
      <form>
        <p>Drug</p>
        //Provide onChange handler to your input's
        <input type="text" name="drug" value={drug} onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

        <p>disease</p>
        <input type="text" name="disease" value={disease} onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

        <p>type</p>
        <input type="number" name="type" value={type} onChange={this.myChangeHandler} />

        <div>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default MyForm
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ny5ynr)

Comment: I made all the changes and the problem still exist

Comment: @RaslanDyab, In that case, you need to provide the codepen for the same. So that I can review and tell you the solution.

Comment: note : my working directory not in the client/src ,since i use mvc express i have one file in the view index.js

Comment: Now, after editing all file , the react app not rendering any thing in the browser

Answer (score -1):

This error happens in many different circunstances. For example, either when you call a component that has some bug on it or you invoqued it incorrectly.

```
import React from "react";
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drug: "",
      disease: "",
      type: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { drug, disease, type } = this.state;
    const myChangeHandler = event => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };
    return (
      <form>
        <p>Drug</p>
        <input type="text" name="drug" value={drug} />

        <p>disease</p>
        <input type="text" name="disease" value={disease} />
        <p>type</p>
        <input type="number" name="type" value={type} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default MyForm;
```

By adding the const on the function, the component renders without problem. Make sure you invoque it correctly from outside as well. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import MyForm from "./form";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Testing</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MyForm />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Remember that when using export default, it is not necessary to use brackets to import the component.